# How to use MySQL user-variables with ADO.NET

Tags: mysql, ado.net, ado

MySQL SQL commands can contain user variables that start with '@'.

The MySQL ADO.NET connector also uses '@' for command parameters.

Is there a way to escape the '@' character so I can use a user-variable in an SQL statement sent to MySQL via ADO.NET?

---

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
UPDATE company 
    SET next_job_id = @jobid:=next_job_id+1 
    WHERE company_id = @companyid; 
SELECT @jobid;
```

Where @jobid is a MySQL user variable and @companyid is a parameter.

Answer (score 7):

It's a connection string option - "Allow User Variables=true"

When set to true, parameters are prefixed with '?'.

Update: I've written up more on this, including how to get this to work with ADO.NET and Subsonic.  [See Here](http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/55-Subsonic-and-MySQL-User-Variables).