# use of DECLARE for MySQL LOAD DATA statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run this query from a .Net application

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'testsFile.txt' 
INTO TABLE Test  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
IGNORE 1 LINES  
(idTest, SampleID, Analyst, @Analysed, Device, Comments, @TotalRUL, @RULOne, @RULTwo, @RULThree, @RULFour, Uploaded) 
SET  
Analysed = nullif(@Analysed,''), 
TotalRUL = nullif(@TotalRUL,''), 
RULOne = nullif(@RULOne,''), 
RULTwo = nullif(@RULTwo,''), 
RULThree = nullif(@RULThree,''), 
RULFour = nullif(@RULFour,'')
```

When I run this query from MySQL Workbench everything works fine, but when I use my .net application to run the query I get the following exception:

> Parameter '@Analysed' must be defined.

I don't think I can use a declare statement outside of a stored procedure and I cant use a stored procedure due to my use of the LOAD DATA statement

What to do? Is this checkmate?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can't. If your query works with Workbench, this sounds like a .net bug.
I suggest you try "stupid" solutions like using backticks (after the @ and after Analyzed... sorry, Stack Overflows autoformatting doesnt allow me to show you what I mean) or changing the variable's name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think my .Net program is treating the variables starting with @ as parameters. And since I have not used any, this causes the error. I've tried surrounding the variables with backticks like `@Analysed`

Comment: I don't know if I was able to express what I mean - and stackoverflow formatting doesn't help. The start backtick should be between @ and A. This way MySQL understands it is a session variable. If not, it considers it as a local variable. Maybe it was already clear, but I wasn't sure...

Comment: I think I know what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

[How to use MySQL user-variables with ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929792/how-to-use-mysql-user-variables-with-ado-net) 
seems to have the answer to this
I needed to add "allow user variables" to the connection string